# Me salta error de índice no definido en la variable

Tags: php

La intención es que me salga un formulario sin abrir otra página. El tema es que me salta el error de que el ***index "name" no está definido***. Entonces, ¿cómo podría evitar esto?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ads</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="nombre">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if($_POST['name']=="sanchez"){echo "bien ".$_POST['name']." xd.";}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Deseas que el mensaje salga sin que la página se recargue al enviar el formulario o simplemente que no aparezca ese mensaje de advertencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El mensaje que te aparece en tu página debería ser similar a éste:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: `name` in `archivo.php` on line `nº línea`;

Es un mensaje de advertencia, no de error, que te está informando que has tratado de acceder a un índice de una matriz que no existe en la línea del archivo PHP indicado en el mensaje. Una variable no definida se convierte en un valor `NULL` en la práctica ([ver documentación](http://php.net/language.types.null)).

Este tipo de malas prácticas pueden dar origen a fallos en el funcionamiento de una aplicación, por lo que el código debe ser corregido.

Para ello debes comprobar si está definido o no el índice de `$_POST`, antes de hacer uso de él, con la función [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset).

A continuación tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ads</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="nombre" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == "sanchez") {
  echo "bien ", htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']), " xd.";
}
?>
```

El operador [`&&` (`Y` lógico)](http://php.net/operators.logical) funciona de la siguiente manera:

Si el lado izquierdo del operador `&&` es:

- `true`: evaluamos la parte derecha para determinar el resultado.
- `false`: el resultado es `false` y no se evalúa la parte derecha.

Es decir, si `isset()` dice que la variable no está definida (el índice `name` de `$_POST`) nunca llega a hacerse la comparación `$_POST['name'] == "sanchez"`, por lo que nunca saltará la advertencia de índice no definido.

Además, he hecho uso de [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/isset) para enviar al navegador el contenido de una variable de cuyo contenido no tenemos control. De esa manera evitarás que tu página sufra ataques de inyección de HTML/JS/CSS.